# How to find dependants of custom metadata records?

Tags: custom-metadata

Whereas when you lookup a field in an object there is a button - 'Where is this used'

How can you ascertain (easily?) where a custom metadata record is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have VS Code and your metadata in source control, it should be pretty easy to search against all the metadata in the IDE with whatever search term (custom metadata type, a field on that metadata type, etc). You can leverage `files to include` or `files to exclude` if you don't want profiles to display or are looking for references in specific files (ex. Apex Classes).

`CTRL + Shift + F` or `Edit --> Find in files`

[image]

Otherwise, you could look for free options that help visualize/pull dependencies off of your org. One that comes to mind is [sfdc-happy-soup](https://happysoup.io/) (I have no affiliation with it). The [repository](https://github.com/pgonzaleznetwork/sfdc-happy-soup) is available as well if you wanted to spin up your own instance of it.